# What is the purpose of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, behavior

I am new to this site, and it has been very helpful recently in helping me learn C# programming. I have read all the rules, but I can't seem to understand what the purpose of this site is.

When I post something, I get downvoted, or posters simply think I am trying to have someone write my program for me. I am currently a student going to college, and I am taking programming classes.

If I don't fully understand what the end result should be, I ask for clarification. Maybe I am not posting or wording my questions right, but all I have gotten in the sense of bulk replies are: "Well, he just wants us to do his homework," "Why wait 4 months to continue learning," "Google it," "Go to the MSDN library," etc.

Then, my question gets downvoted. Or I get a generic response of "why do you think it should be doing what you have written?". If I knew I wouldn't be asking the questions.

I thought that the purpose of this site was to promote learning, and to create a palate of understanding and assistance between newbie programmers and veteran programmers – not to have a gaming reward system, or a lackluster of responses.

I mean, I am cool with it, and I can deal with it. Just curious when the site went south of its original purpose. Or maybe (for clarification), when the site went beyond its original scope and became a vetted response site.

Comment: The purpose of this (and all other [se] sites) are to be a collection of knowledge. It has never been a tutoring service, a homework completion service, or a code writing service. This is abundantly clear in both the [tour] page and the [help]. There is nothing *south of its original purpose* or *beyond its original scope*. It's always had the purpose and goal of being a collection of knowledge and information. There are tons of other sites that are designed to be other things; Google and Bing can find them for you.

Comment: *"The purpose of this site I thought was to promote learning, and to create a palate of understanding and assistance between newbie programmers and veteran programmers"* - no, that is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The purpose of Stack Overflow is not to teach you programming.

There are a wide variety of tutorials, guides, books, etc. available for that type of thing. Sure, asking and answering questions sometimes has that secondary effect (in fact, it probably has that effect more often than not), but it's not the primary purpose.

Questions and their answers are meant to act as a repository of knowledge: when you ask something, it shouldn't be "I can't figure out this assignment – help?"; rather, it should be about a specific problem that could be relevant to others in the future.

Taking a cursory glance at your questions, I see that you've run into some trouble with moderation on the site and some users who aren't too happy with the way you're using the site.

For example, this:

> I have an application assignment from school that I have been working
>   on and have gotten stuck on. I am not understanding some of the
>   concepts to complete my program. It is simple and I have the basic
>   structure down. Could someone assist me in understanding and
>   completing my program?

is much too specific to you (yet paradoxically also quite broad). Any answers it garners are unlikely to help future users unless they happen to take the same class and have the same assignment.

You say:

> ...posters simply think I am trying to have someone write my program for me.

That's why. The way you've introduced the question I referenced above lends itself to that assumption.

> Just curious when the site went south of its original purpose. Or maybe (for clarification) when the site went beyone its original scope and became a vetted response site.

I'm not sure why you think the site has gone "south"; this is and always has been the purpose of Stack Overflow:

> [Stack Overflow] is by programmers, for programmers, with the ultimate intent of collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world. No matter what programming language you use, or what operating system you call home. Better programming is our goal.
>   <sub>[Source](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This helps. I'll be sure to reword my questions so they are not too broad and keep to the point. The going south comment was from information read from many different prior users. I assume they were just unhappy. Again thanks for the clarification you did help me understand more, the purpose of the site.

Comment: @JoeVanHorn That's understandable, given that [Meta's most famous question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) proclaims so.

Answer (score 7):

To **build a library** of **detailed answers** to every question about programming:

[image: tour]

<sub>Source: [Site Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)</sub>