Why, exactly, is opting to delete your account, then opting to later return to the site, not recommended if you are question banned?
If you are question banned, rate limited to 1 question per 6 months, and then you delete and recreate your account, you will be limited 1 question per week. This is by design because otherwise they would just reinstate the full 6 month ban if you recreate your account instead of the 1 week limit. Based on my interpretation of that answer, the goal of the 1-week limit after deleting/rejoining is to stop persistent low-quality question askers who never improve, but cut some slack for users who were just off to a bad start but later improved.
To my experience lifting the 1 per week rate limit is much easier than lifting the question ban. And many times your questions are unsalvageable and cannot be improved, so not much is lost by losing ownership of the questions and the ability to improve them. And even if they are technically salveagable, starting over and asking a well-received question to lift the 1 per week rate limit is usually much easier than going to great lengths to salvage a barely salvageable question.

In light of the above, why is deleting a question-banned account and then later returning to the site so discouraged?
Why would they make a feature that is by design and then turn around and say that invoking the feature is abuse of the system?
What are you supposed to do instead if your questions are unsalvageable and there is nothing you can do to edit them to improve them? Like yeah, if you have questions downvoted -5 or more, closed as a duplicate of multiple questions, or caused by typos, or are not about programming, and no reasonable amount of editing could fix them, like what are you supposed to do?

Note: This makes no mention of deleted accounts, and thus does not really answer this question.
This answer even says:

We're happy to give you an almost clean slate, but we must also protect the quality of the resource that we're building.

So why are they apparently not happy to give us, even an 'almost' clean slate, because doing so is discouraged and might get you temporarily banned?
Responses:

Evading a question ban is against the rules. If caught the new account will be deleted and the original account will suspended for Evading the question ban. The deletion of a profile which is question banned to my knowledge is not an automatic process. "What are you supposed to do instead if your questions are unsalvageable and there is nothing you can do to edit them to improve them?" - Ask one question every 6 months until you prove the need to rate limit your account isn't required.

I am not referring to making a separate account with new credentials, only to the act of self-deleting my account and then rejoining the community with the same network user and same credentials. The 'original' account is deleted and the 'new' account is not a separate profile. And besides, if I will be completely honest, I would take a temporary ban which in my first-offense case was one week, wait the ban period out, and then I have my 'almost' clean slate, over having to wait up to several years to lift myself out of question ban the 'expected' way.

"So why are they apparently not happy to give us, even an 'almost' clean slate" - bans are not a punishment, they are a measure to protect the knowledge base from further damage. Measures as serious as that are not revoked on a whim.

That is sort of missing the point. Why would they create a feature intended to give people an 'almost' clean slate, and then turn around and ban people who try to get their 'almost' clean slates this way? If so, why do they do this instead of just reinstating the question ban in full when you delete/recreate your account.

One thing to note is that the "by design" answer you linked to is ~10 years old. Something that someone (a developer(?) who no longer works for SE) wrote 10 years ago should be suspected of being out-of-date. Especially if it seems to contradict current policy.

When, exactly, was the change established, that deleting and recreating your account to get an 'almost clean slate' is no longer an 'acceptable' practice? I would expect these changes in policy, along with their ostensible reason, to be documented somewhere. And if the policy changed, why did the system not change to reflect this? P.S. I know that the person who wrote that answer, is in fact, a former community manager, Tim Post.

probably answered here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376806 or at least it has relevant arguments.

"This is by design because [...]" Instead of inferring from the answer, the more relevant answer seems to be the one referenced there. That one explicitly says "We're happy to give you an almost clean slate [...]".

FWIW, it's pretty clear why it is not recommended to recreate your account - because you'll get punished even more severely! It seems the question you actually should ask is why you get punished if you recreate your account, counter to policy established elsewhere.

Evading a question ban is against the rules.  If caught the new account will be deleted and the original account will suspended for Evading the question ban.  The deletion of a profile which is question banned to my knowledge is not an automatic process.  "What are you supposed to do instead if your questions are unsalvageable and there is nothing you can do to edit them to improve them?" - Ask one question every 6 months until you prove the need to rate limit your account isn't required.

One thing to note is that the "by design" answer you linked to is ~10 years old.  Something that someone (a developer(?) who no longer works for SE) wrote 10 years ago should be suspected of being out-of-date.  Especially if it seems to contradict current policy.

"So why are they apparently not happy to give us, even an 'almost' clean slate" - bans are not a punishment, they are a measure to protect the knowledge base from further damage.  Measures as serious as that are not revoked on a whim.


You will no longer be able to edit your deleted questions in order to fix them.
You will no longer be able to see your deleted questions in order to flag them for undeletion or undelete them yourself.
You will likely still be banned and because of 1. and 2. you will have lost your main way out of the situation.

If your questions are really unsalvageable then

Learn to use search to find existing questions. Maybe you don't need to ask any questions at all.
Ask one stellar question every six months. Research it and research it to make sure it's a really great question.

